# SoundCloud API: filter favorites by user? (or any other parameter for that matter)

Tags: api, soundcloud, favorite

Is it possible to make an API request that returns only favorited tracks by a specific uploader? I tried:

https://api.soundcloud.com/me/favorites.json?contact_id=...

and

https://api.soundcloud.com/me/favorites.json?user_id=...

I also tried just searching favorites https://api.soundcloud.com/me/favorites.json?q=...

but with all of my trials, I always got the exact same response as without parameters (in the [API console](http://developers.soundcloud.com/console))

I am most interested in the first problem: making an API request to get favorited tracks by a specific uploader, but being able to filter favorites by genre/tag, bpm, etc would certainly be useful and interesting as well! Am I overlooking anything or is this not possible with SoundCloud's API? I don't want to have to get ALL the users' tracks or ALL of the favorites in order just to get all the favorites by that user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way currently to filter by the owner of the favorited track. The best thing to do would be to grab a list of favorites using the `/me/favorites` endpoint, then filter in your application logic. Unfortunately there are no filters that work with that particular endpoint.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer! Adding filters to the favorites endpoint would be a great new API feature. I will look into caching favorites locally in the meantime

Comment: No problem! I've passed it on to the search team. I agree that it'd make sense to have the same filters on tracks and favorites.